# how to Calling JavaScript in a WebBrowser control from C# in such a situation

Tags: c#, javascript, browser

sorry, my poor English,my question is as following:

Calling JavaScript in a WebBrowser control from C# in ordinary way:
JavaScript

```
function showMe()
```

{
     ...
}

C#

```
webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("showMe");
```

that is ok!

but how to call in such situation:

html:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="App.followcancel('1880161672',this,'0','A','B');return false;">hello</a>
```

c#:

```
webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript(????????)
```

I don't know how to write the correct paremeter to achieve the onclick's javascript

anyone help me,thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

Something like this (if you set id of the link to "mylink"):

```
HtmlElement el = webBrowser1.Document.All["mylink"];
object obj = el.DomElement;
System.Reflection.MethodInfo mi = obj.GetType().GetMethod("onclick");
mi.Invoke(obj, new object[0]);
```

Comment: Or you can inject your javascript function that executes onclick from javascript and then call that function with webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript

Answer (score 1):

Following the example you've given:

```
webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("App.followcancel('1880161672',this,'0','A','B')");
```

Edit: This example is broken.

You would need to replace 'this' with `document.getElementById('mylink')`  (assuming an `id` attribute is set with the value `mylink`) or use the approach given by HABJAN.

Comment: this will not work as 'this' parameter is in the wrong context.

Comment: Ah, good point - had missed that in the question. Thought it was just how to invoke the code in the onclick.

Comment: I like the new idea with document.getElementById('mylink')